# SQL Casting Error (Updated Post)

Tags: sql, sql-server

**New Question** 
 I have researched the web on using the cast feature in SQL. I followed same format as the examples, but still doesn't work. Any suggestions? It gives me the same error messages as below.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
update dbo.TableName
set cast(columnName1 as decimal (9,1)) = 10,
    cast(columnName2 as decimal (9,1)) = 11
where ... etc
```

**Previous Post:**

```
When compiling my code, I get this error message: "Microsoft.Rules.Data: Data loss might occur when casting from Integer to Decimal(9,1)." So I put a basic cast in there (see below) and for some reason it doesn't work. Any suggestions? I get the following error messages:

       -- 1). SQL 80001: Incorrect syntax near'0'. Expecting '(', or SELECT.
       -- 2). SQL 80001: Incorrect syntax near '9'. Expecting '(', or SELECT.
       -- 3). SQL 80001: Incorrect syntax near ';'. Expecting CONVERSION.
       -- 4). SQL 46010: Incorrect syntax near 0.

    exec dbo.Name
         @variable1,
         cast((0) as decimal(9,1)),
         @variable2;
```

Comment: Use `0.0` instead of `0`. Then you don't need to cast, which BTW works for me without errors

Comment: That is not an error but a warning. You must have turned on all warnings are errors. Validation rules violations are not errors.

Comment: Thanks @juergend that did the trick!! If you add it as an answer, I will mark it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to cast it. If you use

```
0.0
```

instead of

```
0
```

then you will already have a decimal number representing zero.